# Can I have a side income without registering it as a business

Tags: canada, small-business, income

I am full time employed. If I want to generate some income from a side hobby-business by buying and selling gift cards, at what point in time do I need to register as a business/corporation with the CRA? If I am making more than a certain amount/year from the side business?

I just do not want to do unnecessary paperwork and pay accountant fees unless required by law.

Comment: Are you thinking of doing it as a personal hobby, or as an actual business?

Answer (score 2):

If you do business under your name, you don't need to register your business.  Your business will be treated as a sole proprietorship.  If your revenue exceeds 30,000 (or wish to collect GST for the government) then you will have to register with the CRA for a GST account, but that is free.

Comment: More info here https://www.sba.gov/content/sole-proprietorship-0